# Register custom type in Qt with QJsEngine

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qjsengine

I have a custom class named LObject, with a method "test" i want to call.I have a  method registered in a QJSEngine that returns an instance of LObject.
I get the error message when executing the method :

```
"Error: Unknown method return type: LObject"
```

I tried to register my type with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, but then i can't call the method of my LObject.

What's the way to do it ?

Edit : A Minimal example with 3 files

server.h :

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <qqml.h>



class TObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
public :
    TObject(QObject * parent = nullptr, const QString & data = "") : QObject(parent) ,m_data(data){}
    TObject(const TObject & other) : QObject() ,m_data(other.m_data) {}
    ~TObject(){};
    TObject& operator=(const TObject & other) { m_data = other.m_data;return *this;}
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getData() { return m_data;}
    Q_INVOKABLE void setData(const QString & data) {m_data = data;}
private :
    QString m_data;
};


class Server : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public :

    QQmlEngine * newEngine()
    {
        QQmlEngine * ret = new QQmlEngine(this);
        ret->rootContext()->setContextProperty("Server",this);
        return ret;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE TObject newTObject() { return TObject();}
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TObject)
#endif // SERVER_H
```

main.cpp :

```
#include "server.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Server s;
    QQmlEngine * e = s.newEngine();

    QQuickView view(e,nullptr);
    view.setSource(QUrl("test.qml"));
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

test.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.9

Text 
{
    function test()
    {
        let t = Server.newTObject() //test.qml:8: Error: Unknown method return type: TObject
        t.setData("TEST")
        return t.getData()
    }

    text : test();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to register it to QQemlEngine with `qmlRegisterType` or `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`?

Comment: @Amfasis I don't want to use Qml here, just javascript. But I tried to register it with qmlRegisterType, and it did'nt work

Comment: Then I don't understand why you tagged it with qml, and your use-case neither

Comment: @Amfasis It's related to qml, because QmlEngine inherits QJSEngine. If thought that if you know how to declare C++ type to qml, you should know how to do it with javascript

Comment: Didn't know that ;-) in that case I think you have to define the LObject in a JavaScript? But please share some more code, so we can reproduce the situation

Comment: `qmlRegisterType` is a `QQmlEngine` member function although is is derived from `QJSEngine`. There is no another way to expose a C++ class to QML except of using `qmlRegister***` functions.

Comment: @Amfasis Well there is not much to say about the code. LObject is just a simple class, with Q_INVOKABLE Methonds.
folibis I tried to use a QmlEngine instead of QJSEngine, but I get the same error message. I registered my class with QML_ELEMENT, with qmlRegisterType and Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, but i still get the same error message

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

```
qmlRegisterInterface<TObject>("TObject",1);
```

and then the methods have to return a TObject*.

Answer (score 0):

Registering [QMetaType::qRegisterMetaType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) should fix your issue. In short, QT meta-object needs this to match the return type's name to your class' name:

```
qRegisterMetaType<TObject>();
```